# What exactly is contained in the SQL Server Shared Feature Directoy vs. Instance Root Directory?

Tags: sql-server

What exactly are contained within the SQL Server Shared Feature Directoy vs. Instance Root Directory? Any benefit in putting these onto different drives other than the default C:\? 
[image]

[image]
Note: I do understand the advantages of changing the Data Directories for user databases, tempdb etc... like below:
[image]

Comment: I wouldn't want to research the answer to the first question, but the answer to the second question is "no."  You only really need to use different volumes for things that are I/O intensive, and whatever is installed there isn't going to cause a lot of I/O on the directory.

Comment: well i was just wondering in general what was contained in there, but the bigger question was the 2nd question.... thanks Tony